# XSD validation tool

Tags: xml, eclipse, validation, xsd, notepad++

I'm a complete newbie to XSD, so please forgive me if this question is plain stupid. I'm writing my XML Schema in Eclipse (Kepler). There, in particular, I can validate my .xsd file directly by simple right-click on the .xsd file in my project, and selecting 'Validate'. Everything was going OK until I realized that I would like to use XSD 1.1 (in particular, for assertions) which Eclipse does not support. I did some googling to find that Notepad++ has this nice 'XML Tools' plugin that one can use to validate an XML file against an existing schema (XSD). My problem is that (for the time being) I don't want to validate an XML but rather validate my XSD itself, and thus I do not have a schema against which I would like to validate. So, how can I validate an actual xml schema 1.1 file? Any tools for that? Can I use the 'XML tools' plugin for that?

Note added: by validation (which I maybe used incorrectly) I understand all sort of checks for syntax (?) correctness.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: An XSD schema is an XML file like any other. What do you mean by validating your XSD file? Any validation tool will output warnings and errors about your schema if it does not follow the rules laid out by the Schema specification.

Comment: It does not make sense to validate one single file, you have to validate it against something else. If your intent is really to validate your XSD schema, yes, there are schemas and a DTD from W3C for that.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I edited my question. As mentioned, I'm very new to this, so maybe used the word 'validation' incorrectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference between validating an arbitrary XML file against your XML schema document and validating your XML schema against another schema.

This is because an XML schema is a regular XML file in its own right. As such, it must be well-formed and valid (both criteria can apply to all XML documents). It is well-formed if it adheres to the [XML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/) and it is valid if it adheres to the [XML Schema specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/).

Now, I assume that by `all sorts of checks for syntactical correctness` you mean that well-formedness should be ensured (a single root element, all tags properly closed etc.) and the document should be a proper XML schema.

You have several options:

- find an online service to check the validity of your XML schema
- find an IDE that is similar to Eclipse, but supports XML Schema 1.1
- continue to use the tool you are working with, but treat your XML schema as the XML file you'd usually validate against a schema. Validate it against the [official W3C XML Schema for Schema documents](http://www.w3.org/2009/XMLSchema/XMLSchema.xsd) (or the [official DTD](http://www.w3.org/2009/XMLSchema/XMLSchema.dtd)).

I won't elaborate on the first two options since asking for tools is off-topic on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Do you get anything else apart from "Unable to parse schema file"? That's too cryptic to be useful. The link you refer to is about _processing_ (that is, interpreting) an XML schema, rather than checking its well-formedness and validity. Sure you did not invert the process (validate the W3C Schema against your own)?

Comment: Yes, absolutely sure I did not invert the process. I deleted the comment as it is maybe related only to Notepad++ rather than the XSD itself. One important question, though, that would let me understand the things more generally: what's the role of these processors? That is, if I will provide Eclipse/Notepad++ with the linked (canonical) schema from 2009 (which mentions assertions) as the schema against which I would like to check/validate my (new) schema, will I still depend on the specifics of Eclipse/Notepad++ "version"?

Comment: I.e., should I be concerned with the fact that my IDE is "old"? Or, rather, by merely providing the "newest" canonical schema from the link, I can be sure that some solutions from XSD1.1 included in my developed schema will pass all the correctness tests.

Comment: An XSD schema processor is the agent that actually interprets the XML Schema language and performs the validation. It takes an XML file (to validate) and an XSD file (to validate against) as input. Usually, the processor tests whether both input files are well-formed XML documents at the start. Then, it determines if the content of the XML file matches the constraints defined in the XSD file.

Comment: It is difficult to say whether your IDE will accept Schema 1.1 functionality - perhaps there is more to it than merely validating it against a meta schema for XML Schema 1.0. The only reliable way of finding out is to try and validate a schema document with 1.1 elements (e.g. assertions).

Comment: Eclipse still doesn't have support for XSD 1.1 in Mars.  I use a proprietary XML plugin for Eclipse, but this is a sad state of affairs.  XSD 1.1 has been out since 2012.

Comment: I have the same problem with Eclipse IDE and XMLBeans (well, being deprecated, it is expected that XMLBeans does not conform with 1.1 specs, but Eclipse should be up to date!)